# Simplify algebraic quantities

Tags: simplifying-expressions

After some computations, I obtain a complicated quantity that depends on a real variable $x$, that I can verify numerically is null (at least) for $x \in [0,0.2]$. I would like Mathematica to simplify this expression to $0$, when assuming that $x \in [0,0.2]$. But it is not working, with the basic line

```
FullSimplify[-2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1 + x)] + 2 Sqrt[3 + 4 x (1 + x) - 2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1+ x)]] + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(1 + 2 x (1 + x)) (3 + 4 x (1 + x) - 2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1 + x)])] + Sqrt[ 2 + 4 x (1 + x) (1 +  4 x (1 + x) - 2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1 + x)])], {0 < x < 0.2}]
```

Do you think it is possible to help Mathematica simplify this expression?

Comment: This proves your claim: `In[90]:= Resolve[
 ForAll[x, 
  0 < x < 1/5, -2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1 + x)] + 
    2 Sqrt[3 + 4 x (1 + x) - 2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1 + x)]] + 
    Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(1 + 2 x (1 + x)) (3 + 4 x (1 + x) - 
         2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1 + x)])] + 
    Sqrt[2 + 
      4 x (1 + x) (1 + 4 x (1 + x) - 2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1 + x)])] == 0]]

Out[90]= True`

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how you constructed a function that has that "zero over an interval" property.

Comment: Indeed, thank you. I have two expressions that should be equal for this interval, but since one of them involves square roots, it might be that the two expressions differ out of this interval.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

```
Reduce[-2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1 + x)] + 
   2 Sqrt[3 + 4 x (1 + x) - 2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1 + x)]] + 
   Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(1 + 2 x (1 + x)) (3 + 4 x (1 + x) - 
       2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1 + x)])] + Sqrt[
   2 + 4 x (1 + x) (1 + 4 x (1 + x) - 2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1 + x)])] != 
  0, Reals]  (*x < 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[3]) || x > 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[3])*)
```

then:

```
expr[x_] := 
 Which[x < 1/2 (-1 - Sqrt[3]) || 
   x > 1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[3]), -2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1 + x)] + 
   2 Sqrt[3 + 4 x (1 + x) - 2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1 + x)]] + 
   Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(1 + 2 x (1 + x)) (3 + 4 x (1 + x) - 
       2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1 + x)])] + Sqrt[
   2 + 4 x (1 + x) (1 + 4 x (1 + x) - 2 Sqrt[2 + 4 x (1 + x)])], True,
   0]
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. I am wondering whether this could help me, because I am coming across many terms like this. So ideally, I would like Mathematica to be able to simplify it, without having to look at them one by one. But I may be able to write a script to make your analysis systematically.

Comment: `identifyZeroes[expr_, vars_, domain_ : Reals] := 
 With[{notZero = Reduce[expr != 0, vars, domain]},
  Which[notZero, expr, True, 0]
  ]`  identifyZeroes[y (x^2 - y), {x, y}]`

Comment: Thanks. I just don't manage to modify the domain to fit my example. For instance, how can I ask to Reduce over [0,0.2]? The examples I found were only with usual domains such as Reals, Integers,...